# Formulario Modal com abas não abre combo

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Montei um formulário modal com duas abas, e os campos da primeira aba funcionam perfeitamente, mas na segunda aba os combobox estão vindo com o style=display: none; e isto esta sendo feito sozinho, alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser isso?

Comment: você pode compartilhar o código?

Comment: Por favor compartilhe o código. Você pode usar https://jsfiddle.net/ como editor online.